# Debian 11 template on Hyper-V

Tags: debian, hyper-v

I used to run Debian 10 on a Hyper-V (Windows 2019) Server and I could set up a "template" VHD and copy it every time I needed a new Debian server, thus getting around the installation.

Now I'm looking into Debian 11 (currently "Testing" or "Bullseye") and the old procedure does no longer seem to work, neither with automatic partitioning nor with manual partitioning. Hyper-V says "SCSI Disk (0,0) The boot loader did not load an operation system."

Does anybody have any idea whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's just a bug in testing?

Comment: What is the "old procedure"? How exactly did you install Debian?

Comment: "Old procedure" refers to: shut down the installed VM, copy the VHD and configure a new VM using the copy as the hard disk. For Debian 11 I tried manual partitioning first, because ESP and swap are IMHO oversized, but also automatic partitioning. Otherwise I used the graphical installer with pretty much the default settings, except for my apt-cacher as proxy. And the installation worked, since the original VM boots fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, it seems I'm *really* getting old and forgetful. I ran into the same issue 2 years ago, when starting with Debian 10 on Hyper-V. I even thanked the author of [this article over on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1247959/hyper-v-create-vm-with-existing-vhdx) for his nice step-by-step instructions.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: It seems that Hyper-V UEFI is buggy and looks in the wrong place for the .efi file(s). I'm not really sure how UEFI works in detail, but the link in the answer provides step-by-step instructions. You only have to do it once for the "template" VM, then you can copy the VHD file for future VMs